# Android:Two elements are behind other when I using Fragments, but shoulds follow each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin

I've this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue_bg">
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pager1" />
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/StartFindButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager1" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/StartFindButton"
    android:id="@+id/pager2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Pager1, startFindButton, pager2 shoulds follow each other.

And I do it in the fragment:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TwoPagerLayout, container, false);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmentTx.Add(Resource.Id.pager1, SearchOptionsFragment);
        fragmentTx.Add(Resource.Id.pager2, ProcedureListFragment);
        fragmentTx.Commit();
        return view;
    }
```

But in the result I have Pager1, startFindButton behind Pager2. Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

`android:layout_below="@id/StartFindButton"`

instead of

`android:layout_below="@+id/StartFindButton"`

See the difference? The + is missing, in case you don't :) Do that for all your views.

With + you add a new id, without it you refer to that id.